# How to stroke string, beginning with' ~'?

Tags: javascript, html, css, stroke

guys! 
I need to do the following. There is a field to enter. When he introduces something beginning with ~ all of the following must be fortified with a frame(directly in the field to enter or in the list below). How to implement it? (Without jQuery, ok?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add a tag around the part of the string you want to be surounded

```js
input = document.getElementById("input")
result = document.getElementById("result")

input.onkeyup = () => {
  // you need to know if the ~ is a start or end of framing
  isFramed = false
  // the resulting HTML is kept in this variable
  // adding directly to result.innerHTML cause browser to autoclose the <span> immediatly
  resultContent = ""
  
  for (let cara of input.value) {
    // if the current char is a ~
    if (cara === '~') {
      // and there is a frame
      if (isFramed) {
        // close the frame
        resultContent += "</span>"
      } else {
        // else start a new frame
        resultContent += "<span style=\"border: 1px solid black\">"
      }
      // inverse isFramed value
      isFramed = !isFramed
    } else {
      // for every other char just copy it as is
      resultContent += cara;
    }
  }

  // finaly set result's innerHTML to the builded string
  result.innerHTML = resultContent
}
```

```html
<input id="input"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

note : you can reduce the resulting HTML size by moving the style of the `<span>` to a css file